# Why are these Lie derivative equations equal?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, lie-derivative

[Nakahara](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068) says on page 279 that the Killing equation

$$
X^\xi\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\mu X^\kappa g_{\kappa\nu}+\partial_\nu X^\lambda g_{\mu\lambda}=0
$$

can be written as

$$
(\mathcal L_X g)_{\mu\nu}=0
$$

Why are these two equations equal? I tried to use the definition of the Lie derivative like this:

$$
(\mathcal L_X g)(Y,Z) = \mathcal L_X(g(Y,Z)) - g(\mathcal L_XY,Z)-g(Y,\mathcal L_XZ)
$$

but I can't see how I can use this to prove their equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're stuck, but $\mathcal L_X g$ is a $(0,2)$ tensor, with components given by

$(\mathcal L_X g)_{\mu\nu} := (\mathcal L_X g)(\partial_\mu, \partial_\nu) = \mathcal L_X(g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)) - g(\mathcal L_X \partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)-g(\partial_\mu,\mathcal L_X \partial_\nu).$

Then you can use the fact that

$\mathcal L_X \partial_\mu = [X,\partial_\mu] = -[\partial_\mu, X^\kappa\partial_\kappa] = X^{\kappa}[\partial_\mu,\partial_\kappa] -\partial_\mu(X^{\kappa})\partial_\kappa =-\partial_\mu(X^{\kappa})\partial_\kappa$

to get

$ - g( \mathcal L_X \partial_\mu , \partial_\nu ) = - g( - \partial_\mu(X^{\kappa})\partial_\kappa, \partial_\nu )= \partial_\mu X^{\kappa}g_{\kappa\nu}.$

Use the same scheme on the last term.

For the first term, use the fact that $\mathcal L_X (f) = Xf$ for a vector field $X$ and function $f$ (the argument $g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu) = g_{\mu\nu}$ is just a function).